# Google Earth Engine calculation of new Index NDRS

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, vegetation-index

I want to calclulate this index in GEE. I managed to calculate the DRS, but I do not understand how to calculate the NDRS. Can you help?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Flaraemsinghoff%2FStart%3ANDRS

Equations: DRS = sqrt ((RED)²+(SWIR)²)

And: NDRS = (DRS-DRSmin)/(DRSmay-DRSmin)

[image: Screenshot of NDRS calculation (Huo, L.; Persson, H. J.; Lindberg, E: (2021): Early detection of forest stress from European spruce bark beetle attack, and a new vegetation index: Normalized distance red & SWIR (NDRS). In: Remote Sensing of Environment 255 (2021) 112240) (]

**CODE:**

```
Map.centerObject (geometry)

//Cloudfiltering
var s2 = Images
.filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 10)
.filterDate ('2018-02-01', '2018-10-01')
.filterBounds (geometry);

//Pixel
function fieldpixel (image){
  var scl = image.select ('SCL');
  var veg = scl.eq (4);
  var soil = scl.eq (5);
  var mask = (veg.neq (1))
  .or (soil.neq (1));
return image.updateMask (mask);}
var s2 = s2.map(fieldpixel)

//Mask Clouds
function masks2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select ('QA60');
  
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask= 1 << 10;
  
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
    .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  
   return image.updateMask (mask); }
   

   
   //DRS
   var addDRS = function(image) {
       var DRS = image.expression('sqrt (((RED)*(RED)) + ((SWIR)*(SWIR)))',
       {'SWIR': image.select ('B11').divide(10000),
       'RED': image.select ('B4').divide(10000).rename('DRS'),
  });
       return image.addBands(DRS);
       
     };
     
  var s2 = s2.map (addDRS);
print (s2)
     
  var DRS = s2.select(['DRS']);
   var DRSmed = DRS.median();
   var pal = ['black', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'lightgreen', 'green'];
  
   Map.addLayer(
     DRSmed.clip(geometry),
     {min: 0, max:1, palette: pal},
     'DRS')
     
     
  // NDRS
  // = ((DRS- DRSmin)/(DRSmax-DRSmin))
```

**EDIT:**

So. I experimented with the code for VCI. It worked and an image appeared. Is this the right way?

```
var DRS = s2.select(['DRS']);
   var DRSmed = DRS.median();
   var DRSmin = DRS.min()
   var DRSmax = DRS.max()
   var pal = ['black', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'lightgreen', 'green'];
  
   Map.addLayer(
     DRSmed.clip(geometry),
     {min: 0, max:1, palette: pal},
     'DRS')
     
var getNDRS = function(image){
  var NDRS = image.subtract(DRSmin).divide(DRSmax.subtract(DRSmin))
  
  // return image.addBands(vci) // both output togther
  return image.addBands(NDRS) // only the vci
}

var s2 = s2.map (getNDRS);
print (s2)

var NDRS = s2.select(['DRS_1']);
   var NDRSmed = NDRS.median();

   var pal = ['black', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'lightgreen', 'green'];
  
   Map.addLayer(
     NDRSmed.clip(geometry),
     {min: 0, max:1, palette: pal},
     'NDRS')
```

Comment: Please share the geometry as "Anyone Can Read". It is creating error

Comment: I hope now it will work

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still not working.

Comment: I do not know why that is why I add the code here

Comment: The error it's showing up is similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51036103/collection-loadtable-not-found-in-gee

Answer (score 2):

You can try out this using the `unitScale()` function

```
      var minmaxs2= function(image){image.reduceRegion({
       reducer: ee.Reducer.minMax(),
       geometry: geometry,
       scale:10,
       maxPixels: 10e9
    })
};
var news2 = s2.map(minmaxs2)
var ndrs = news2.select('DRS')
                 .unitScale(news2.get('DRS_min'),news2.get('DRS_max'))
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I think it will be work. But I tried to add it, and a error occured: "User-defined methods must return a value". Maybe there is a lacks a "return" ?

Comment: Yes, return statement is probably missing.

Comment: @L.J.E. kindly accept the answer if it solved your problem.